# Twitter Sign up screen

Tags: iphone, twitter

My question is two fold. Firstly the screen that gets generated when the user does not have a twitter account and clicks on the sign up button in (Native Twitter iPhone App)  like the image below. Is it Default screen or is it created programmatically?

If it is default iOS Screen, then how do i get my app to generate it.

If it isn't then what process will I be following exactly to sign the user up with Twitter given I have his credentials

[link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5bbfb9&s=5)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is default screen. No need to add extra code for it. If you call twitter share and you weren't signed in, in twitter it will show a dialog box. click settings will navigate to twitter sign in.Clicking create new account will navigate to sign up page. There is a bug in twitter app in older versions of iPhone simulator.but in new iPhone simulator you can sign in , dont know sign up actually works. [image: My defalt Twitter sign up look like this]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know what you are  saying. but as far as i know if i click `Settings` it will open the Settings App, while pushing my own app to the background mode. I however dont want that to happen

Comment: It's like that.If you dont want to do that then you should use twitter 
API in your App.So no need to use native twitter app.

Comment: Hmmm.. Heres a bummer theres no public new user signup Twitter API available yet. Looks like ill have to drop the idea of letting my app create new accounts all together. Thanks for your time